# ActiveRecord's finding methods? Help to join models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I  have two models already created and properly working:

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :grand_prixes
end

class GrandPrix < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :track
end
```

My database schema is:

```
create_table "tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "track_name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "lenght"
    t.integer  "pit_boxes"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "ac_track_name"
  end
add_index "tracks", ["ac_track_name"], name: "index_tracks_on_ac_track_name"




create_table "grand_prixes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "gp_date"
    t.integer  "max_slots"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "track_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end


  add_index "grand_prixes", ["track_id"], name: "index_grand_prixes_on_track_id"
```

I am able to can find the GrandPrix that are associated with a Track by id, but I want to find the GrandPrix in the table by the id of the track previously searched by  track's name (a variable that comes from another site):

```
GrandPrix.where (track_id: 2)
```

This works and returned the GP I want.

I want to search by name:

```
GrandPrix.where (Track.name = "thenameIwant")
```

and to return my id:

```
SELECT id FROM WHERE tracks tracks.name LIKE 'thenameIwant';
```

Then it would be something like this:

```
GrandPrix.where (Track.id = SELECT id FROM WHERE tracks tracks.name LIKE 'thenameIwant')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `joins` keyword to join the two relations:

```
GrandPrix.joins(:track).where(tracks: {name: "thenameIwant"})
```

Note the plural "tracks" in the where clause since your table name is "tracks"

Comment: So much thanks, I got it working this way thanks to your idea 


`GrandPrix.joins(:track).where(tracks: {ac_track_name: "spa"})`